# opensearch blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized]

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, opensearch, opensearch-security-plugin

I'm trying to setup an opensearch cluster on kubernetes.
when settings my nodes nothing fails but I get an error at a certain point and
this is my stateful set:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.global.name }} --> opensearch
  namespace: {{ .Values.global.namespace }}
  clusterName: {{ .Values.global.clusterName }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.global.name }}
  annotations:
    majorVersion: "{{ include "opensearch.majorVersion" . }}"
spec:
  serviceName: "opensearch"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.global.name }}
  replicas: {{  .Values.replicas }} ---> 3
  template:
    metadata:
      name: {{ .Values.global.name }}
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.global.name }}
        role: master
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: init-sysctl
          image: busybox
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command:
            - sysctl
            - -w
            - vm.max_map_count=262144
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
        - name: increase-fd-ulimit
          image: busybox
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: [ "sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536" ]
      containers:
        - name: "{{.Values.global.name }}-master"
          image: opensearchproject/opensearch
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: '8Gi'
              cpu: "1"
            requests:
              memory: '8Gi'
              cpu: "1"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
              name: rest
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 9300
              name: inter-node
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: node.name
              value: opensearch
            - name: cluster.name
              value: "{{ .Values.global.clusterName }}"
            - name: node.master
              value: "true"
            - name: node.data
              value: "true"
            - name: node.ingest
              value: "true"
            - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
              value: "opensearch-0"
            - name: discovery.seed_hosts
              value: "opensearch-0"
            - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
              value: "-Xms4g -Xmx4g"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: {{ .Values.global.name }}
              mountPath: /etc/opensearch/data
            - name: config
              mountPath: /usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch.yml
              subPath: opensearch.yml
            - name: node-key
              mountPath: {{ .Values.privateKeyPathOnMachine }}
              subPath: node-key.pem
              readOnly: true
            - name: node
              mountPath: {{ .Values.certPathOnMachine }}
              subPath: node.pem
              readOnly: true
            - name: root-ca
              mountPath: {{ .Values.rootCertPathOnMachine }}
              subPath: root-ca.pem
            - name: admin-key
              mountPath: {{ .Values.adminKeyCertPathOnMachine }}
              subPath: admin-key.pem
              readOnly: true
            - name: admin
              mountPath: {{ .Values.adminCertPathOnMachine }}
              subPath: admin.pem
              readOnly: true
            - name: client
              mountPath: {{ .Values.clientCertPathOnMachine }}
              subPath: client.pem
              readOnly: true
            - name: client-key
              mountPath: {{ .Values.clientKeyCertPathOnMachine }}
              subPath: client-key.pem
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: opensearch-config
        - name: config-opensearch
          configMap:
            name: config
        - name: node
          secret:
            secretName: node
            items:
              - key: node.pem
                path: node.pem
        - name: node-key
          secret:
            secretName: node-key
            items:
              - key: node-key.pem
                path: node-key.pem
        - name: root-ca
          secret:
            secretName: root-ca
            items:
              - key: root-ca.pem
                path: root-ca.pem
        - name: admin-key
          secret:
            secretName: admin-key
            items:
              - key: admin-key.pem
                path: admin-key.pem
        - name: admin
          secret:
            secretName: admin
            items:
              - key: admin.pem
                path: admin.pem
        - name: client-key
          secret:
            secretName: client-key
            items:
              - key: client-key.pem
                path: client-key.pem
        - name: client
          secret:
            secretName: client
            items:
              - key: client.pem
                path: client.pem
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: {{ .Values.global.name }}
        labels:
          app: {{ .Values.global.name }}
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: "20Gi"
```

when I set use this definition, at some point I get this error:

```
[ERROR][o.o.s.c.ConfigurationLoaderSecurity7] [opensearch] Exception while retrieving configuration for [INTERNALUSERS, ACTIONGROUPS, CONFIG, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, NODESDN, WHITELIST, AUDIT] (index=.opendistro_security)
org.opensearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException: bl
ocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];
```

now if I'm trying to set the nodes:

```yaml
- name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
  value: "opensearch-0.opensearch.search.svc.cluster.local,opensearch-1.opensearch.search.svc.cluster.local,opensearch-2.opensearch.search.svc.cluster.local"
- name: discovery.seed_hosts
  value: "opensearch-0.opensearch.search.svc.cluster.local,opensearch-1.opensearch.search.svc.cluster.local,opensearch-2.opensearch.search.svc.cluster.local"
```

It fails on the same error, only this time this warning comes before.

```
[opensearch] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [opensearch-0.opensearch.search.svc.cluster.local, opensearch-1.opensearch.search.svc.cluster.local, opensearch-2.opensearch.search.svc.cluster.local] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{opensearch}{SKON7g98RnyQsz6SAYqWRg}{GkUCV8mISZqITHiU0LDEzQ}{10.20.1.103}{10.20.1.103:9300}{dimr}{shard_indexing_pressure_enabled=true}, {opensearch}{qRuv6YgYQjGVatLGRGfPtQ}{62EmR4a_Sb-nhV9_7F05aA}{10.20.2.137}{10.20.2.137:9300}{dimr}{shard_indexing_pressure_enabled=true}, {opensearch}{8flMQsmxQEGN4LeBMemHsQ}{6zNV_pTZRnO6YneCzvOA4Q}{10.20.3.204}{10.20.3.204:9300}{dimr}{shard_indexing_pressure_enabled=true}]; discovery will continue using [10.20.2.137:9300, 10.20.3.204:9300] from hosts providers and [{opensearch}{SKON7g98RnyQsz6SAYqWRg}{GkUCV8mISZqITHiU0LDEzQ}{10.20.1.103}{10.20.1.103:9300}{dimr}{shard_indexing_pressure_enabled=true}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0
```

When I try to run in the pod the security setup script

/usr/share/opensearch/plugins/opensearch-security/tools/securityadmin.sh -cd ../securityconfig/ -icl -nhnv -cacert /usr/share/opensearch/config/certificates/root-ca.pem -cert /usr/share/opensearch/config/certificates/admin.pem -key /usr/share/opensearch/config/certificates/admin-key.pem

it fails too, output:

```
Cannot retrieve cluster state due to: null. This is not an error, will keep on trying ...
  Root cause: MasterNotDiscoveredException[null] (org.opensearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException/org.opensearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException)
```

```
kubectl get svc opensearch -o yaml
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"clusterName":"gloat-dev","labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"opensearch-gloat-dev-search"},"name":"opensearch","namespace":"search"},"spec":{"clusterIP":"None","ports":[{"name":"http","port":9200},{"name":"transport","port":9300}],"publishNotReadyAddresses":true,"selector":{"app":"opensearch"},"type":"ClusterIP"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2022-01-17T12:21:56Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: opensearch-gloat-dev-search
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
      f:spec:
        f:clusterIP: {}
        f:ports:
          .: {}
          k:{"port":9200,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:port: {}
            f:protocol: {}
            f:targetPort: {}
          k:{"port":9300,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:port: {}
            f:protocol: {}
            f:targetPort: {}
        f:publishNotReadyAddresses: {}
        f:selector:
          .: {}
          f:app: {}
        f:sessionAffinity: {}
        f:type: {}
    manager: argocd-application-controller
    operation: Update
    time: "2022-01-17T12:21:56Z"
  name: opensearch
  namespace: search
  resourceVersion: "173096782"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/search/services/opensearch
  uid: ec2a49a1-f4e8-4419-9324-1761b892aeca
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 9200
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9200
  - name: transport
    port: 9300
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9300
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true
  selector:
    app: opensearch
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

error log trace:
https://pastebin.com/MtJp9iwf (loops)

Comment: Can you run `securityadmin.sh` command with `--diagnose` flag and include the response in the question body?

Comment: @KamolHasan sure

Comment: @KamolHasan updated

Comment: can you share your `opensearch` service yaml? `kubectl get svc opensearch -o yaml`. And the whole pod log in pastebin or something.

Comment: @KamolHasan added